# How would you divide all the negative values in a dictionary in C#?

Tags: c#, dictionary, key

I have a `Dictionary<string, double>`. I looped through the values to remove all the positive double values.

I need to divide the remaining negative values together and then round it to 10 decimal points.

```cs
double divisionSum = 1;
foreach (var entry in dic.Values)
{
    divisionSum /= entry;
}
```

This doesn't work as 1 divided by a negative number does not return it's initial value for the first instance of division.

For example, if the values of the Dictionary was -2, -4, -8, -5 I would want divisionSum to equal 0.0125. Also cannot use any Math() methods

Comment: So to clarify, you have a dictionary with values (for example) -1, -10, -3, -5. And you want to divide them all together to get (in this example) .0067? Where is `divisionSum` coming from? It's in your code but not mentioned in your question.

Comment: Can you clarify by adding some sample input data and the expected output, please?

Comment: divisionSum is the double variable that I want to store the result of the divisions into. So each loop it will divide divisionSum by the entry, and then store that result back into divisionSum

Comment: This is not a sum and it will result in `1 / -2 / -4 / -8 / -5 = 0.003125`. So, please write down the calculation step by step, so that we can reproduce the result `0.0125`. Adding the reciprocals will not help either. First, you must solve the problem mathematically. Then only start writing C# code.

Comment: Yes, that's my problem. How would I rectify this? I want to -2 / -4 / -8 / -5 and then store it in a variable. But that is difficult using values of a dictionary as there is no indexing

Comment: Your loop seems to work just fine. [Take a look](https://dotnetfiddle.net/lFERw8)

Comment: That's returning the wrong result however as divisionSum starts off as 1. I need a way to put the first entry into divisionSum for the first loop but not any subsequent loop

Answer (score 1):

Loop through your list (ok, it's a dictionary, but you only care about the values, so it's basically a list) starting at index 1 not the default of 0, but first assign the value of index 0 to your result.

```
var foo = new List<double>{-1, -10, -3, -5};

double result = foo[0];
for (int i = 1; i < foo.Count; i++)
{
    result /= foo[i];
}

result = Math.Round(result, 10);
result.Dump();
```

and since the question was modified after the above answer to require `Math` library be excluded, here's a variant:

```
var foo = new List<double>{-1, -10, -3, -5};

double result = foo[0];
for (int i = 1; i < foo.Count; i++)
{
    result /= foo[i];
}

result = Convert.ToDouble(result.ToString("#.0000000000"));
result.Dump();
```

Comment: The OP said they weren't permitted to use Math() methods.

Comment: They edited that in after my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It works if you start with the first value instead of `1`. To have better control on accessing individual value, I have converted the values from the dictionary into an array:

```cs
double[] values = dic.Values.ToArray();
double divisionSum = values[0];
for (int i = 1; i < values.Length; i++) {
    divisionSum /= values[i];
}
// divisionSum => 0.0125
```

Note that the for-loop starts at index 1 to skip the first value at index 0 which was already assigned to `divisionSum`.

The advantage of a dictionary is that you can look up values very quickly by key. They are not particularly good when you have to loop over the values. It would be better to use a list or array for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

The following corrects the code so that `divisionSum` is initialised with the first value and the loop divides in the remaining values. The last line does the rounding to 10 decimal places without using any Math() methods, which was a requirement.

```
var valuesList = dic.Values.ToList();
var divisionSum = valuesList[0];

for (var index = 1; index < valuesList.Count; index++)
{
    divisionSum /= valuesList[index];
}

divisionSum = Convert.ToDouble(divisionSum.ToString("#.0000000000", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

Comment: `var divisionSum = valuesList[0];` will not do if 1st item is not negative or if `valuesList` is empty

Comment: @DmitryBychenko OP states that they have already removed the positive values from the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

You can query the dictionary with a help of *Linq*:

```
using System.Linq;

...

// Let me keep the name; result looks a better however
double divisionSum = dic
  .Values
  .Where(item => item < 0)      
  .DefaultIfEmpty(0.0)          // put the default value here: 0, 1 or whatever 
  .Aggregate((s, a) => s / a);
```

For no Linq solution we have to initialize *within the loop* (let's have `firstTime` flag) with the 1st negative item:

```
double divisionSum = 0.0; // put default value here: 0, 1 or whatever
bool firstTime = true;

foreach (var item in dic.Values) {
  if (item < 0) {
    divisionSum = firstTime ? item : divisionSum / item;

    firstTime = false; 
  }
}
```